# Taylor series of functions

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions, euler-maclaurin

Consider the Taylor series of the function

$$\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{E_n}{n!} x^n$$

Prove that $E_0 = 1, E_{2n-1} = 0$ and, for $n \ge 1$, $$E_{2n} = - \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} C_{2l}^{2n} {E_{2l}}$$

The hint given was to consider $\cosh(x)$.

I understand that the function is actually the reciprocal of $\cosh(x)$, however, I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: $$1=\cosh x\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{E_n}{n!} x^n$$ Now use $\cosh(x)$ expansion.

Comment: May i know how to make use of the 1 to derive any relation on E? @labbhattacharjee

Comment: So if we take the comment above and blindly replace $\cosh(x)$ with equation $5$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html). Then we will be looking at the product of two series. We can then evaluate the [cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of the two series. Then maybe something good will happen? I don't know but that's probably what I would do...

Comment: I can't seem to simplify the Cauchy product, any hints on that? @Mason

Comment: On the left hand side divide numerator and denominator by $e^{x}$ and get $sech$, I think you can compare both Taylor series term by term as $sech$ is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the Taylor series expansion of $\cosh x$ which you can find e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Taylor_series_expressions). 
\begin{align*}
\cosh x = \frac{e^{2x}+1}{2e^x} = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2l}}{(2l)!}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{1}&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{E_k}{k!}x^k\right)\frac{e^{2x}+1}{2e^x}\tag{1}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{E_k}{k!}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2l}}{(2l)!}\right)\\
> &=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{E_k}{k!}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{1+(-1)^l}{2}\frac{x^l}{l!}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{E_k}{k!}\cdot\frac{1+(-1)^l}{2l!}\right)x^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1+(-1)^{n-k}}{2}E_k\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Coefficient comparison of (1) and (2) gives
\begin{align*}
  E_0=1\quad \text{and}\quad E_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1+(-1)^{n-k}}{2}E_k\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\tag{3}
  \end{align*}

> From (3) we get for even index
>   \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{E_{2n}}&=-\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\frac{1+(-1)^{k}}{2}E_k\\
>   &\,\,\color{blue}{=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k}E_{2k}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad n\geq 1}
>   \end{align*}
>
> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{2e^{-x}}{e^{-2x}+1}=\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}\\
> \end{align*}
>   we see the function $\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}$ is even and we conclude $\color{blue}{E_{2n-1}=0, n\geq 1}$.

Comment: A function such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ is called *even*, not *odd*.

Comment: @Tom-Tom: Thanks, typo fixed.

Comment: Isn't cosh the reciprocal of the expression in the first line?

Comment: @Nebu: No. See e.g. *[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Definitions)*.

Comment: +1. I started answering that OP's request and then got distracted with my students. And then I saw you beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 2):

Because the OP asked for some clarification and because I haven't done this type of thing very often (ever?) and it's good to practice I have tried my best here. This isn't a complete answer just a supplement. This really is just the details of the $4$th equality in Markus Scheuer's answer box above. The one that says:

$$ \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{E_k}{k!}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{1+(-1)^l}{2}\frac{x^l}{l!}\right)
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{E_k}{k!}\cdot\frac{1+(-1)^l}{2l!}\right)x^n $$

The details may be tricky for someone (like me) who hasn't done this often before so here they are in their details. We note that

$$\cosh(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A_n}{n!}x^n$$

Where $A_n=0$ when $n$ is odd and otherwise $A_n=1$. Markus Scheuer cleverly writes this as $\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}$ We are motivated to rewrite the series like this so it is in the format of a typical power series so we can easily apply the Cauchy product. As seen in the wiki:

$$ \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j x^j\right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k \text{  where  }  c_k=\sum_{l=0}^k a_l b_{k-l}$$

So in this case we have $a_i=\frac{A_i}{i!}$ and $b_j=\frac{E_j}{j!}$ and then $c_k =\sum_{l=0}^k \frac{A_lE_{k-l}}{l!(k-l)!}$

To make this a little cleaner we can multiply by $\frac{k!}{k!}$ so that we can make the ${k\choose l} =\frac{k!}{l!(k-l)!}$ appear. The other motivation for doing this trick would be that we want a binomial coefficient to appear because it's in your given prompt. 
Then we have $c_k=\sum_{l=0}^k {k \choose l} \frac{A_l E_{k-l}}{k!}$. And the rest is shown in the other answer.

Comment: (+1) for this helpful supplement.

Comment: Actually this post does a decent job explaining the 5th equality and the 4th equality is just an application of the cauchy product. I can change this later.